# How to emulate press 'Enter' with paramiko Python?

Tags: python, ssh, server, paramiko

I was trying to make a simple code that runs `apt update` and `apt upgrade` on a server using python paramiko. After entering these commands, I confirm the installation with `stdin.write("Y" + '\n')` and then the problem occurs. If I do it manually on the server, then a window pops up (screenshot 1), in Python it looks like this (screenshot 2)
I tried sending the command `stdin.write("1" + '\n')` but that didn't give any results.

- screenshot 1

  [image]
- screenshot 2

  [image]

---

```
def sendCommand(command):
    print("Sending command")
    if (client):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
            if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                while stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    alldata += stdout.channel.recv(1024)

                print(str(alldata, "utf8"))

def sendCommand_Text(command, text):
    print("Sending command")
    if (client):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
        stdin.write(text + '\n')
        stdin.flush()

        stdin.write("1" + '\n')
        stdin.flush()

        stdin.write('\n')
        stdin.flush()
        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
            if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                while stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    alldata += stdout.channel.recv(1024)

                print(str(alldata, "utf8"))

sendCommand("apt update\n")

sendCommand_Text('apt upgrade\n', "Y")
```

Comment: "... and then the problem occurs" -- what problem occurs? please post a [repro].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd try running `apt upgrade -y`, to see if it makes the upgrade non-interactive.

Secondly, if you want a larger degree of control against an interactive terminal I'd suggest using `expect`. Expect allows for performing specific actions given particular conditions. In python you can use `pyexpect`.
In your case, after having successfully login with pyexpect you could use something like:

```
child.expect("What do you want to do about modified configuration file sshd_config?")
child.sendline("1")
```

NOTE: It is not trivial to make everything work in the first place with pyexpect, but I've been using it in the past for a lot of hacky things with interactive terminals and it helped a lot.